# Enable Kerberos on Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos, jaas

Trying to make Kafka Cluster Kerberos-aware. However, I keep getting auth errors when I try to start Kafka Server.

The easiest way to ask this question for me is by splitting down into 3 questions.

- Is there any software that needs to be on the server before one can start working on kerberising some service; Apache Kafka in my case *(prerequisite software)*.
- Why is the Kafka server trying to authenticate on start-up? and with what? (the error suggests it is trying to connect to Zookeeper).

  ERROR An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]) occurred when evaluating Zookeeper Quorum Member's  received SASL token. Zookeeper Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient).
- Does Zookeeper need to be kerberised as well for Kafka server to be kerberised?

Comment: Yes, Zookeeper also needs SASL authentication via a Kerberos keytab on the brokers. Although this largely depends how you've configured Kafka

Comment: thanks for your reply. Zookeeper starts fine ( with krb config ) but I still get the same error when I try to start Kafka server.